# How to transpose multiple column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with the following columns titles and a row example:

```py
df_test = pd.DataFrame([(20211014,2539683,108783,'NPL',-20000,'(-) ลดตามยอดผ่อน',-20000,'(-) NPL Exit',-2000,'(-) NPL Exit', 1), 
                        (20211014,2539683,108783,'NPL',0,'',0,'',0,'', 0)],
                  columns=['DATA_DATE', 'ID', 'Response','TYPE', 'M1', 'R1', 'M2', 'R2', 'M3', 'R3','PERCENT'])
```

Original Dataframe:

```
DATA_DATE       ID  Response TYPE     M1                R1     M2            R2    M3            R3  PERCENT
0   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL -20000  (-) ลดตามยอดผ่อน -20000  (-) NPL Exit -2000  (-) NPL Exit        1
1   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL      0                        0                   0                      0
```

Target Dataframe:

```
DATA_DATE       ID  Response TYPE  PERCENT            Reason    M1    M2    M3
0   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL        1  (-) ลดตามยอดผ่อน -2000     0     0
1   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL        1      (-) NPL Exit     0 -2000     0
2   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL        1      (-) NPL Exit     0     0 -2000
```

Advice is much appreciated on an approach to this.

Comment: nottp, why did you roll back my edit? Was it wrong?

Comment: I don’t understand your edit please suggest me again thank you. Sorry i’m beginner.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's ok! I made the edit because it looked like the first few rows of the Reason column had some unnecessary spaces before them, which made it hard to read.

Comment: ok thanks. Do you have solution for this question? :)

Comment: It seems like it should be easy to solve, but actually, I can't really figured it out. I've tried a bunch today, but I haven't got it. I'd wait for a few days though; probably by the weekend someone will hang out and get it. :)

Comment: I decrease the column for easy read already advice me please. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Do the column names always alternate, e.g. Mxx then Rxx, etc.? Because the older versions of the question had Cxx columns.

Comment: Oh sorry. I changed column name because it easy read.

Comment: It's not a problem, I just need to know because my solution will depend on the column names if possible. What are the columns in real life?

Comment: What are the columns in real life? Ans. Use current column in post thank you. :)

Comment: Ok!! :) Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do (`df` your dataframe):

```
df1 = pd.concat(
    [
        df.iloc[0, 5:-1:2].T.reset_index(drop=True).rename("Reason"),
        df.iloc[0, 4:-1:2].T
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={"index": "columns", 0: "values"})
          .pivot(columns="columns", values="values")
          .fillna(0)
    ],
    axis=1
)
df2 = (
    df.iloc[:1, list(range(4)) + [df.shape[1] - 1]]
      .loc[[0] * df1.shape[0], :]
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)
result = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   DATA_DATE       ID  Response TYPE  ...            Reason     M1     M2    M3
0   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL  ...  (-) ลดตามยอดผ่อน -20000      0     0
1   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL  ...      (-) NPL Exit      0 -20000     0
2   20211014  2539683    108783  NPL  ...      (-) NPL Exit      0      0 -2000

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```